# Combination Algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

I need a combination of *n* fields where each field can be equal to null or not null. For each combination, the fields cannot be repeated. Basically, there should be a total of *2^n* combinations.

**Example:**

if I have 2 fields `A` and `B`, the combinations in the output should be:

```
A != null and B != null
A != null and B == null
A == null and B != null
A == null and B == null
```

if I have 3 fields A, B, and C, the combinations in the output should be:

```
A != null and B != null and C != null
A != null and B != null and C == null
A != null and B == null and C != null
A != null and B == null and C == null
A == null and B != null and C != null
A == null and B != null and C == null
A == null and B == null and C != null
A == null and B == null and C == null
```

I don't know what this combination is called, so how can I do this in code where the number of fields is a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: It's the power set of `{A, B, C}` if you consider that `!= null` means "present in the subset" and `== null` means "not present in the subset".

Comment: I don't get what you need, you need the algorithm for generating all those possibilities? another thing is where do you put those returns?

Comment: @Martin - thanks i think i get an idea about what you mean regarding power sets.. can you give me an example?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley The output should be exactly what i have shown in my question

Comment: This looks like a state machine to me, for given states do something.

Comment: @Paul There are examples here: http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/combinatorial-algorithms.html#power-set.

Comment: What are you planning to use this "auto-generated code" for? Maybe there is alternative solution to your problem that doesn't need all this code

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley yes i specifically need a string output for this.. just a background on the program im working on, this is a tool to generate test scenarios for QA.

Comment: i would not be able to do something with a better code than Dmitry, sorry :)

Comment: The question is very unclear. I think you fall into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Basically, you don't expose what you are trying to do, but how you think it should be done. That said, I guess you should take a look at Enum with `[Flags]` attribute. This may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a *generator* of such lines you can use *Linq*:

```
   int count = 2;

   var lines = Enumerable
     .Range(0, 1 << count) // 1 << count == 2 ** count
     .Select(item => String.Join(" and ", Enumerable
       .Range(0, count)
       .Select(index => ((Char) ('A' + index)).ToString() + 
                        ((item >> index) % 2 == 0 ? " != null" : " == null"))));


   // Let's print out all the lines generated
   Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

For `count = 2` the output is

```
  A != null and B != null
  A == null and B != null
  A != null and B == null
  A == null and B == null
```

**Edit:** A small modification lets you put your own names:

```
  String[] names = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };

  var lines = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 1 << names.Length) // 1 << count == 2 ** count
    .Select(item => String.Join(" and ", Enumerable
       .Range(0, names.Length)
       .Select(index => names[index] +
                        ((item >> index) % 2 == 0 ? " != null" : " == null"))));

  // Let's print out all the lines generated
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

Comment: thanks but the fields im using are variables.. they are not literally "A", "B", or "C"..

Comment: @Paul Adrian Pena: a small modification (see my edit) lets you provide your own names

Comment: i think i got it.. thanks a lot.. this is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

I usually stick to simple recursion in cases like this, because it's so easy to understand. No explanation, I'll just let the (untested) code talk for itself:

```
public void Generate()
{
    Create("", 0);
}

private string[] names = new[]{ "A", "B", "C" };

public void Create(string s, int current)
{
    if (current != 0)
    { 
        s += " and ";
    }

    if (current != names.Length)
    {
        string c1 = s + names[current] + " == null"; // case 1
        string c2 = s + names[current] + " != null"; // case 2

        Create(c1, current+1);
        Create(c2, current+1);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```